# Spark Streaming - Filter dynamically

Tags: filter, apache-spark, streaming, dynamically-generated

I have a Spark streaming job. I want to apply filter to my input RDD.

I want to fetch filter criteria dynamically each time from Hbase during each spark streaming batch.

How do I achieve this ?

I can create connection object using Map partitions once.

But with in spark filter how do i achieve the same thing ?

Comment: Depending on your filter criteria you might be able to achieve it with a `join`. You'd have to give a more full example of what you are trying to do, but if the left side of the join is your Spark Stream, the right side would be a set of criteria. If none of the criteria apply, the join results in no rows -- it filters them.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the right approach is writing a filter function of your own (pseudocode):

```
DStream<Integer> intDstream= someIntegerIntoDStream;
intDstream.foreachPartition{
     create HBase connection here if you need it for a batch
     while(arg0.hasNext()){ //here you have an iterator
          Integer current = arg0.next();
          create HBase connection here if you need it for each element
          //Here is your filter function:
          if( current meets your condition )
               arg0.remove();
```

So what happens is that you are running on your executor and you manually picking each element, applying a condition to it and removing it if it meets your criteria.